# surround a function with a macro

Tags: c

I've got a .c file, containing some functions like

```
void foo(void)
{
...doSomeStuff...
}
```

Now, I want to surround this function with some code, resulting in

```
void foo(void)
{
    ...additional stuff...
    {
        ...doSomeStuff...
    }
    ...do more additional stuff...
}
```

In short, want to take the whole body of the function and place it in an "outer" function.

I tried to get it working with a macro that can be used like this:

```
MAGIC_MACRO(foo)
{
...doSomeStuff...
}
```

This way, the macro user (or me) just has to take the foo function's head and replace the void return type with the MAGIC_MACRO stuff. The MAGIC_MACRO shall expand to the "additional and more additional stuff" part.

Ok, I thought that would be easy. I tried to implement it like these macros containing a do-while(0) loop. Well, the big problem is the "more additional stuff" part, which has to be after the old function's body.

Any idea on that?
Regards, lugge

Comment: I don't see the point of this at all. Why not simply call `foo` from another function? If you want to "replace" foo, just change the name of the original one (with a macro if you really feel like it).

Comment: The use of a macro to "hide" something is a terrible abuse.

Comment: i have removed the c++ tag, since it is apparently a c file. if it is actually a c++ file then add the tag back.

Comment: Mat you may be right. I thought this would be a simple task. But as i read the answers, I guess it is not. Calling foo() from another function may be a solution. Well, the point was to extend foo with some testing code, providing some infos during development. And that without having to add this code by hand. I thought this macro would make it easy to add the test code.

Answer (score 3):

This is not something I'd recommend doing, but you can have the macro create one function containing the entry/exit code, and another containing the code given by the user:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAGIC_MACRO(f) \
    void f##_inner(void); \
    void f(void) { \
        printf("entry\n"); \
        f##_inner(); \
        printf("exit\n"); \
    } \
    void f##_inner()

MAGIC_MACRO(foo)
{
    printf("foo\n");
}

int main(void) {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

The invocation of `MAGIC_MACRO` will create `foo` and `foo_inner` functions, where `foo` calls `foo_inner`. `foo_inner` contains the user code, which allows putting it all after the macro invocation.

[Live example](http://ideone.com/eqIzuZ)

Answer (score 0):

> In short, want to take the whole body of the function and place it in
>   an "outer" function.

the syntax for such a macro would have to take the whole body of the function as parameters, which isn't

```
MAGIC_MACRO(foo)
{
...doSomeStuff...
}
```

but

```
MAGIC_MACRO(foo,
{
...doSomeStuff...
})
```

or maybe

```
MAGIC_MACRO(void foo(void),
{
...doSomeStuff...
})
```

the real problem with the approach is see is that there are special characters, #pragma's and other things which may be found in the bodies and they cannot be transported using a macro parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in several macro combination:

```
#define BEGIN_INT_FUNCTION(name) \
  int name() {\
  do something...

#define END_INT_FUNCTION \
  do something...
  return 0; \
}
```

now you code the function:

```
BEGIN_INT_FUNCTION(name)  // or without argument
{
  function body...
}
END_INT_FUNCTION
```

and you call it like this:

```
int x = name();
```